# Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)?Unable to authenticate php/Mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql, ubuntu, web

I am getting following error:

> "Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)?"
>   Unable to authenticate php/Mysql

I am getting  this error using lamp server on ubuntu.

```
<?php
    $not_login = 0;
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
    {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
        $password = "";
        $con = mysql_connect($servername,$username);
        if ($con) {
            $db = mysql_select_db("ccmsdb",$con);
        }
        else{die(mysql_error());
    }
    $login = "LOGIN";

    $userid=$_POST['userid'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    //$password = md5($password);

    if ($db) {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM client WHERE   `userid`='$userid' AND `password`='$password' ";
        $result = mysql_query($query);
        $rows_count = mysql_num_rows($result);

        if ($rows_count>0) {

            header("Location:../welcome.php");
        }

        else
        {
            $not_login=1;
        }
        if(!empty($data))
        {

        }

    }
}
?>

<html>
       <form action=" " method="post">



        <h1>Log-In</h1>

      <p>   <label for="Userid">User Id:</label>

        <input type="text" name="userid">

    </p>

    <p>

        <label for="Password">Password:</label>

        <input type="Password" name="password">

    </p>
    <button>Login</button>

</form>
```

Comment: `mysql_connect($servername,$username);` you also need to pass the `$password` variable in there, even though none may be setup for it. You also have a whole bunch of spaces in `...             password`

Comment: Please refer to the `mysql_connect` [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php).  This extension is deprecated and has been removed as of PHP7. No new code should be developed that uses on it.

Comment: I added $password but when i clicked Login, nothing happend.

Comment: also, hate to be that guy, but stop using mysql_...... find a more updated tutorial to follow

Comment: ***Step #2 to debugging:*** Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag 
for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: and that folks, is why I always post [a "comment"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34533174/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-nounable-to-authent#comment56807766_34533174) before knowing exactly which animal we're dealing with here. V v V v V v V

Comment: kamranjavaid, it's also a good thing to test a connection with only that in a file. Creating a new file with just the connection and error handling can help you isolate your problem. @Fred-ii-, yep, but that comes with a price. Sometimes people rage that we 'answered' in comments...

Comment: Plus, your question is a repost of http://stackoverflow.com/q/34526010/

Comment: @FirstOne Let them rage; it's but a waste of emotion really and they really should be paying attention, not to mention what century we're in now ;-)

Comment: why is this thread still going. the relevant question has been answered here half a dozen times. OP has a new issue he should post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please refer to the following links.

- [Access denied for user 'root@localhost' (using password:NO)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2995054/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-passwordno)
- ['Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8537531/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no)
- https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost
- [Php/Mysql login authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34526010/php-mysql-login-authentication)

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add password parameter into `mysql_connect` function, adding it as shown below should resolve your issue.

check this modification:

```
       <?php
        $not_login = 0;
        if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
          {
        $servername = "localhost";
        $username = "root";
       $password = "";
        $con = mysql_connect($servername,$username, $password);

...

?>
```

Comment: are you not paying attention to comments? and *"I added $password but when i clicked Login, nothing happend. – kamran javaid 2 mins ago"*

Comment: I added passwrd as parameter, still same issue